# how do I see the history of crontab?

Tags: ubuntu-11.04, cron

I've read a few posts on the web, gone and looked for the file they are mentioning and haven't found it. I'm in Ubuntu 11 and trying to troubleshoot a cron job that isn't running, even though I have it sent to run every 3 minutes. The command in the cron job runs with no errors.

Where does cron store the history of what jobs were run and when? How do I make sure it's enabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron puts the output of the executed script into an e-mail (use the `mail` command to read them) or they go to the system logs.

A cron job usually doesn't run because of a huge amount of assumption. Assuming that something runs right when you (YOU as the user) run it, is a good way to make mistakes.

Typical mistakes are missing rights or invalid path. You should test your script:

- if you can start it as the user of the cron job **without** environment variables
- if you can start it anywhere in the file-system (you should use full paths, not relative ones)

When testing user rights don't use `su - <user>` but `su <user>` as the former will initialize the environment from .bashrc which you won't have by default when cron runs.

Comment: Hmm, mail doesn't seem to be on ubuntu. I get: `
The program 'mail' can be found in the following packages:
 * heirloom-mailx
 * mailutils` neither one is installed though.

Comment: There is no `mail` under Ubuntu, sorry, I was checking this on Debian. 
I set up an erroneous cron line, and it is pushing error messages into `/var/log/syslog` in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: Thanks for that. Looks like it doesn't keep those messages long. I was having issues with cron yesterday and the messages are at most 5 hours old. Bummer.

Comment: please post the cron job line, just to check if the timing is correct

Comment: I believe this one wasn't working correctly. The cron job is working correctly now.  `# Begin Whenever generated tasks for: /mnt/hgfs/projectAlpha/config/schedule.rb
0,15,30,45 * * * * /bin/bash -l -c 'cd /mnt/hgfs/projectAlpha && RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake nightly_tasks --silent >> /logs/tasks.log 2>&1'

# End Whenever generated tasks for: /mnt/hgfs/projectAlpha/config/schedule.rb
` (comment is going to mess it up a bit)

Comment: Also, I don't have the crontab for the one that was going every 3 mins -- it looked the same except for the 0,3,6,9... in the beginning.

Comment: Is everything working now?

Comment: Yes, there was something wrong with the command. I got it working a few days ago and I'm not really sure what the issue was. I think the `/var/log/syslog` is where to go next time I have an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the standard cron doesn't keep a log. Apparently you can cause it to log by adding a `cron.debug       /var/log/cron` entry to `/etc/syslog.conf` then send `syslogd` a HUP signal.

Usually, failed jobs result in email to the relevant user.

A common cause of cron job failure is programs that rely on environment variables or paths that are set during interactive login but not by cron.

Comment: Does /etc/syslog.conf exist in Ubuntu? I don't see it there.

Comment: how can i set this in centos